# Can't play DVDs on Linux Ubuntu laptop

Tags: video, dvd

I can't play a DVD on my Ubuntu laptop. I've tried VLC. A window with a traffic cone opens and the Drive spins for a short time, then stops. Nothing else happens.

Answer (score 3):

It's usually easier to just install the restricted extras package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

If you have any problems the [official Ubuntu documentation on playing DVDs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs) has a good troubleshooting guide as well.

The specific steps outlined in @illuminE's answer are from this page as well, mainly:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
$ sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

#### References

- [RestrictedFormats - Ubuntu official docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats)
- [RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs - Ubuntu official docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I'm new to this. I've done what you suggest, the first line got response that libdvdread4 is already the newest version. the s

Comment: the second line got "Command not found" I'll follow the links and references you give here

Comment: Is the issue only this movie DVD and does the dvd reader work in general? In the reference _slm_ gave there's information on simply using the Media/open disc/ menu in vlc to disable "DVD menus", and I remember that being useful to me once. Also a package which is installed can sometimes be reinstalled, just to make sure, with the `sudo apt-get install --reinstall packagename` command.

Comment: Wow, that worked for me and I have been at this for 6 hours! Thank you.

Comment: @Shane - glad it helped you out!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the proper [codecs and libraries](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs), including *libdbdcss2*:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
```

then

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```