# Can't mount DVD

Tags: dvd

my OS is ArchLinux running on an old ASUS laptop. Recently, I picked a DVD box-set from the store and later realized that they just won't play in my computer. Thinking that the DVD's were faulty I went back to the store and to my surprise they worked quite well when played on the stores dvd-player.

I don't remember playing a DVD in the last few years but I did have a bunch of issues with region specific DVD's, this was quite a while back.

Usually, DVDs' are automatically mounted by Nautilus. I tried mounting the device with `mount`:

```
localhost% sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 ~/cdrom 
mount: /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

I think the problem might very well be hardware related but any pointers would be more than welcome.

Output of the `cd-drive` command at [paste-bin](http://pastebin.com/PpGniiuA).

#### Update #1:

Here are the `dvd*` packages present in my OS:

```
extra/libdvdcss 1.2.13-3 [installed]
  Portable abstraction library for DVD decryption
extra/libdvdnav 4.2.0-2 [installed]
  The library for xine-dvdnav plugin.
extra/libdvdread 4.2.0-1 [installed]
   Provides a simple foundation for reading DVD video disks
```

Output of the `cd-info` command:

```
Disc mode is listed as: Error in getting information
++ WARN: error in ioctl CDROMREADTOCHDR: No medium found
cd-info: Can't get first track number. I give up
```

I should have checked the system logs. Here is what I found from `journalctl` when I tried playing the disc using `vlc`:

```
 -- Logs begin at Sun 2013-10-20 01:18:10 IST, end at Tue 2013-11-05 15:30:23 IST. --
Nov 05 15:30:22 localhost gnome-session[1443]: libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.2.0
Nov 05 15:30:22 localhost gnome-session[1443]: libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.13 for DVD access
Nov 05 15:30:22 localhost gnome-session[1443]: libdvdread: Could not open /dev/sr0 with libdvdcss.
Nov 05 15:30:22 localhost gnome-session[1443]: libdvdread: Can't open /dev/sr0 for reading
Nov 05 15:30:22 localhost gnome-session[1443]: libdvdnav: vm: failed to open/read the DVD
Nov 05 15:30:22 localhost gnome-session[1443]: libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.13 for DVD access
Nov 05 15:30:23 localhost gnome-session[1443]: libdvdread: Could not open /dev/sr0 with libdvdcss.
Nov 05 15:30:23 localhost gnome-session[1443]: libdvdread: Can't open /dev/sr0 for reading
Nov 05 15:30:23 localhost gnome-session[1443]: [0x7f9848009158] dvdread demux     error: DVDRead cannot open source: /dev/sr0
Nov 05 15:30:23 localhost gnome-session[1443]: [0x7f9858005b88] main input error: open of `dvd:///dev/sr0' failed
```

Comment: There should be some output in `dmesg` regarding the type of your dvd device. And then the DVD might use some sort of copy protection.

Answer (score 3):

These are media DVDs or data DVDs? You typically don't mount media DVDs that contain movies and such. Also if this is a media DVD that contains movies and/or TV shows you'll likely need to install `libdvd4` software so that your system can handle the encrypted content on the DVD.

See my answer to this question, titled: [Can't play DVDs on Linux Ubuntu laptop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86284/cant-play-dvds-on-linux-ubuntu-laptop/86287#86287).

#### cd-info

You can use this command, `cd-info --dvd`, to get more information about the installed DVD media. Here I have the Curious George DVD installed in my laptop.

#### Exmaple

```
$ cd-info --dvd
cd-info version 0.82 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Copyright (c) 2003, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2008 R. Bernstein
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
CD location   : /dev/cdrom
CD driver name: GNU/Linux
   access mode: ioctl

Vendor                      : Optiarc 
Model                       : DVD RW AD-7930H 
Revision                    : 1.D1
Hardware                                  : CD-ROM or DVD
Can eject                                 : Yes
Can close tray                            : Yes
Can disable manual eject                  : Yes
Can select juke-box disc                  : No

Can set drive speed                       : No
Can read multiple sessions (e.g. PhotoCD) : Yes
Can hard reset device                     : Yes

Reading....
  Can read Mode 2 Form 1                  : Yes
  Can read Mode 2 Form 2                  : Yes
  Can read (S)VCD (i.e. Mode 2 Form 1/2)  : Yes
  Can read C2 Errors                      : Yes
  Can read IRSC                           : Yes
  Can read Media Channel Number (or UPC)  : Yes
  Can play audio                          : Yes
  Can read CD-DA                          : Yes
  Can read CD-R                           : Yes
  Can read CD-RW                          : Yes
  Can read DVD-ROM                        : Yes

Writing....
  Can write CD-RW                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-R                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-RAM                       : Yes
  Can write DVD-RW                        : No
  Can write DVD+RW                        : No
__________________________________

Disc mode is listed as: DVD-R
CD-ROM Track List (1 - 1)
  #: MSF       LSN    Type   Green? Copy?
  1: 00:02:00  000000 data   false  no   
170: 95:59:74  431849 leadout (968 MB raw, 843 MB formatted)
__________________________________
CD Analysis Report
ISO 9660: 2228814 blocks, label ` CURIOUS_GEORGE                 '
Application: MKISOFS ISO 9660/HFS FILESYSTEM BUILDER & CDRECORD CD-R/DVD CREATOR (C) 1993 E.YOUNGDALE (C) 1997 J.PEARSON/J.SCHILLING
Preparer   : 
Publisher  : 
System     : LINUX
Volume     :  CURIOUS_GEORGE
Volume Set : 
UDF: version 1.02
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I have noticed that I have the packages required for dvd-playback on my system, so I don't think thats the problem.

Comment: @feverDream - try the command `lsdvd`.

Comment: it says it can't find the device /dev/dvd

Comment: @feverDream - `cd-info` or `cd-drive` show anything?

Comment: I haven't tried cd-info and I have the output of cd-drive posted in the question via pastebin

Comment: @feverDream - OK, didn't notice that. This just shows us the capabilities of the drive, not what's loaded. What does `dmesg` say about the hardware?

Comment: @slim,nothing on dmesg but I tried playing the dvd using vlc and had some logs with journalctl. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @feverDream - yeah that's why I originally suggested libdvd css. Some discs can not be decrypted by it. You may need a newer version of it.

Comment: hmm, let see if I can find more info about the error. Thanks for the suggestions slm

Comment: @feverDream - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2071073. Realize you're Arch but might be helpful.

Comment: I have not had such toruble with CD of DVD media since I bought the Blue-ray dirve on this PC 8 or 9 years ago until Ubuntu 22.04 or 22.10 (currently on 22.10).  In recent months I've had bother 'seeing' media in the DVD/CD ROM drive mostly for CD-s and some DVD-s.  Unsettelingly, a couple of CD-s worked fine with SoundeJucer apart from one or two tracks.  Tonight `cd-info --dvd` command was enough to mount a difficult DVD and let VLC play the movie.  I reckon the hardware and the firmware are just _FINE_ for my situation.  Something seems off with auto-mount lately...